# Capturing a callable in a minimal function wrapper

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to avoid the use of `std::function` and allocations when creating a minimal wrapper for my callables. To this end, my wrapper will copy l-value reference objects and move construct from r-value references:

```cpp
template <class F>
class PipelineStep
{
  F _action;

public:
  template <class J>
  PipelineStep(J&& operation) 
    : _action(std::forward<J>(operation) {}

  template <class... Args>
  decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args) {
    return std::invoke(_action, 
                       std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};

// Deduction guides.
template <class T> 
PipelineStep(T&&) -> PipelineStep<std::decay_t<T>>;
```

As it may be obvious, I need the wrapper to create a strong type to provide and overloaded `operator|` to chain pipeline steps together. My question on the aforementioned code is:

- I tried to avoid providing deduction guides but it doesn't seem to work. I'll have to have a forwarding reference constructor to handle temporaries, but without the deduction guides I cannot handle non temporaries. Is there a better way?
- Is my class safe regarding  the lifetime of `_action`? I'm assuming whatever I pass to the constructor, the class will be instantiated containing a value, i.e. no references. Is this correct?
- Using `decltype(auto)` should be the best choice here, to preserve the value category of the `_action`'s return type. Is this correct?
- The deduction guide uses `std::decay_t` to force `F` into a "simple value" type (no references). Is this not necessary?

Comment: You have a typo in your deduction guide, `PipelineStep<T&&>` -> `PipelineStep(T&&)`. Everything else looks clean.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That tormented me when compiling, and I still did the same mistake when posting here. Thanks, will fix

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to avoid the use of `std::function` and allocations

`std::function` does not always allocate. For example, if you pass it a regular function pointer, or a lambda which doesn't capture anything, or at most a single pointer, then it can store everything without heap allocations. If your `F` only allows function pointers, then there is almost no benefit over using `std::function`, and you lose a lot of flexibility. If you use `std::function`, then you also don't need to make the constructor a template, and then you don't need a deduction guide.

To handle temporaries without a deduction guide, you need to add another constructor that takes a `const J&`.

If the type `F` is not a reference, then the lifetime of `_action` is fine. Since the use of `std::decay_t` in the deduction guide removes references, that is fine.

`decltype(auto)` is used correctly here.

Comment: `std::function` still has overhead, even if it decides to not allocate a small object on the heap. If you're certain you only want to store a single type of callable, I see no reason to use it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Correct, which is why I said "*almost no* benefit" :) Although here it seems the goal is to have arbitrary functions captured in a `PipelineStep`, so `std::function` seems more appropriate to me.

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to be handling only one type of callable?